# Execute gradle task after test

Tags: gradle

After executing `test` task in Gradle build I want to always execute additional task which should have access to test result. Something like:

```
task('afterTest') {
    doLast {
        if (testSuccessful) {
            //
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two parts in your question: 1) make a custom task executed always after `test` task is executed,  2) make the test "result" available in this custom task.

1) First part is very simple, you just have to use the dedicated `Task.finalizedBy` method to create a "finalized by" dependency between `test` task and your custom task. (see [Finalizer tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks))

2) Second part is a bit tricky, as there is no simple way provided by Gradle, as far as I know,  to get the "result" (SUCCESS or FAILURE) of `test` task. But you could use API exposed by the [Test Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) to store the number of test in error into a variable and test this counter in your custom task :  here is a working example:

```
ext{
    // counter of test cases in error
    nbTestOnError = 0
}

test {
    // use "afterTest" hook to increment nbTestOnError   counter
    afterTest {  desc ,  result  ->
        if (result.getResultType().equals(TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE)){
            nbTestOnError++
        }
    }
}

task('afterTest') {
    doLast {
        // implement your logic depending on counter value
        if (nbTestOnError > 0) {
            // do something if test failed
        } else{
            // do something when all tests passed
        }
    }
}

// create "finalized by" dependency
test.finalizedBy afterTest
```

**EDIT** : based on important remark in comment from @lance-java : in order to support  *up-to-date check* , you could configure your custom task to be "skipped" if `test` task is not executed. A simple way would be to use Task `upToDateWhen` feature (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:custom_up_to_date_logic)) :

```
task('afterTest') {
    // consider this task "UP TO DATE" if `test` task did not execute
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        !test.didWork
    }
    doLast {
    //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd write the result to disk as a JSON/XML/property file rather than use `ext.nbTestOnError`. You could then use the file as an input to `afterTest` task. This would mean that Gradle's up to date checking / skipping could continue to work.

Comment: @lance-java thanks for this interesting comment. I updated my answer accordingly, using another approach to implement the up-to-date check, that I think is simpler. please comment if you see some drawbacks in this solution.

Comment: Your changes are not what I was saying. You can't rely on variables in the Gradle model. You must use the file system to properly pass outputs/inputs between tasks

Comment: Can you give some tips about how to generate this file from `test` task? I think adding a  `doLast`  block is not possible as it won't be executed as soon as one test case fails.

Comment: I've created an answer detailing what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the other thread, it's best to use the file system to pass values from one task to another. This way the value will be available even if the test task was up to date and skipped. Eg:

```
test {
    outputs.file "$buildDir/test.properties"
    ext.errorCount = 0
    afterTest {  desc ,  result  ->
        if (result.resultType.name() == "FAILURE") {
            errorCount++
        }
    }
    doLast {
        file("$buildDir/test.properties").text = "errorCount=$errorCount" 
    } 
    finalizedBy 'afterTest' 
    ignoreFailures = true
}
task afterTest {
    dependsOn 'test' 
    inputs.file "$buildDir/test.properties"
    doLast {
        def props = new Properties() 
        props.load(file("$buildDir/test.properties")) 
        def errorCount = Integer.parseInt(props['errorCount'])
        if (errorCount) {
           // doStuff
           throw new TaskExecutionException("$errorCount tests failed") 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: As i said in my last comment, Gradle will not execute  your action given in 'doLast' block of 'test' task, if there is one or more test failing, so the file won't be created/updated in this case. This is what i observed by testing this solution. Did you manage to make this solution work?

Comment: Updated to set `test.ignoreFailures = true`. See [ignoreFailures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:ignoreFailures)

Comment: The 'ignoreFailures' is risky I think... if you rebuild a project that failed due to tests, 'test' task won't be executed again and the build will succeed. Not sure this is what we we want.

Comment: You can throw an exception in `afterTest` when `errorCount>0` and you'll get the behavior you require

Answer (score 0):

Building on the [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970400/150884) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990301/150884), use [`org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.afterSuite`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:afterSuite(groovy.lang.Closure)) to save the test result to a file:

```
test {
  afterSuite { descriptor, result ->
    if (descriptor.parent == null) {
      file("$buildDir/test.result").text = result.resultType
    }
  }
}

afterTest.onlyIf {
  file("$buildDir/test.result").text == 'SUCCESS'
}
```

where the `afterTest` task is executed only when the test suite succeeds.